How to select a bond dimension for Matrix Product States (MPS) calculations?
I am trying to get a better understanding of tensor networks and Matrix Product States (MPS) before implementing any code. I will preface this by saying I am very new to these concepts.
My understanding is that the bond dimension sets the upper bound on the entanglement. Thus, a very (computationally) inefficient way to simulate something is to pick a a huge bond dimension, which is upper bounded at $m =d^{N/2}$ where $d$ is the dimension of each site (source).
My question is: given a physical system, how do we know what bond dimension to pick? I know that there should be some sort of game between accuracy and computational efficiency, but are there any general principles one should follow? Do we need to know a priori how entangled the system we are working with is to select the bond dimension?
Related Questions

Connection between bond-dimension of a matrix product state and entanglement

Connection between Bond dimension and Physical Lattice Sites for Tensor Networks


